# mySQL JOIN causing query slowness with AND in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a query to find emails for a specific user where the user either wrote the email (stored in the email table itself) or was cc'ed in the email, stored in another email that is joined to the email table in the query.

This query is very slow. There are about one and a half million emails and a token number of entries in the email_cc table; but the OR in the WHERE clause turns the simple query against the email table into something that takes a factor of 1,000 longer.

How do I rewrite this query to make it performant?

```
**email**
id (PRIMARY)
userid (INDEX)

**email_cc**
id (PRIMARY)
userid (INDEX)
emailid (INDEX)
```

---

```
SELECT email.id, email.userid
FROM email
LEFT JOIN email_cc ON (email_cc.emailid = email.id)
WHERE (email.userid = 5 OR email_cc.userid = 5)
```

---

In response to comments: running this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email.id) FROM email 
LEFT JOIN email_cc ON email_cc.emailid = email.id 
WHERE (email.userid = 468741 OR email_cc.userid = 468741)
```

Gets

```
SIMPLE  email   index   IDX_54469DF4217BBB47    IDX_54469DF4217BBB47    5   NULL    1514520 Using index
SIMPLE  email_cc    ref IDX_8D675752700047D2    IDX_8D675752700047D2    4   email.id    1   Using where
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `emailid`? And can you show the `explain select ...` output?

Comment: Updated question with info.

Comment: I think your where clause should limit userId, not id if you want to filter by specific user. Is is just mistake while rewriting query, or it's your original version?

Comment: Sorry, yes it was a mistake rewriting query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `union` as it would be comparatively faster than `or`. Something like this:-

```
SELECT email.id, email.userid
FROM email
LEFT JOIN email_cc ON (email_cc.emailid = email.id)
WHERE email.id = 5

union

SELECT email.id, email.userid
FROM email
LEFT JOIN email_cc ON (email_cc.emailid = email.id)
WHERE email_cc.id = 5
```

"or" is causing a table scan on the email table even if there are indexes on both email.id and email.userid. A union will convert that into index seek + index scan. (assuming there are indexes for two columns)

Comment: This was fast - yes; we actually did this in code instead of via mySQL as a stop gap solution; but thought this was probably not the correct general approach to this problem; perhaps it is?

Comment: Well as a matter of fact this is a general approach as I have already explained you in my answer that why "union" is better in your case than "or". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you give this a try

**Updated as per OP's comment**

```
SELECT 
  email.id, 
  email.userid
FROM 
  email
WHERE 
  email.id = 5
  OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM email_cc WHERE email_cc.id = 5 )
```

Comment: We did try this actually; it was exactly the same (slow) unfortunately.